# Should I created three images for Apache http server, php and memcached separately?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm dockerizing a php project. My first question is is it a good practice to create three images separately for Apache http server, php and memcached? or it is better to install memcached in php image? If I were to create them separately, how to do the configuration to let Apache http server to support php, in another words, to let them work together?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the images in this way. Put you app into app folder, and if you want connect to memcached the host is "memcached"

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: php:apache
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/var/www/html/
  memcache:
    image: memcached:alpine
```